# JDB Print Global Variables

Tags: java, jdb

I have attached an application to the jdb debugger. I am trying to know the state of the global/class variables through jdb debugger.

```
Class MyClass() {

    private static String myString;

    public void myMethod() {
    // Some code
    }

}
```

Let's say my breakpoint is in myMethod() method. We can print the variables using print / dump command (Please refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdb.html)). I tried to print class variable myString using the command **print myString** when the breakpoint is in the method myMethod(). But it threw the exception - com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: Name unknown: myString. 
I am able to print/dump local variables present in the method myMethod().

Comment: what is the command print myString?

Comment: You have to use `self.myString` to access class variables.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes, the command is 'print myString' after attaching the jdb.

Comment: @campovski Still getting the same error.

Comment: @SnehaV print myString is not valid Java syntax

Comment: @Stultuske  I think he is not literally doing `print myString`... I hope so... At least I expected he didn't...

Comment: @campovski which is why I was asking for the code he does have :)

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication. I have edited the question, please have a look. I am  debugging my application using jdb. I want to know the state of variables. We can print/dump variables using print / dump command. But I am unable to print global/class variables (local variables works fine). Any help would be much appreciated. (And by the way, it's **she** ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `myString` is a static field on the class, you should be able to access it by using a static identifier:

`dump <full-classpath>.MyClass.myString`